# Cleanest way to choose between functions inside loop to avoid overhead?

Tags: c, function, for-loop

I have a function that computes the Minimum Spanning Tree of a graph, and I have two different ways to compute the edge weights in the tree.

The `edge_weight()` function is called inside a few `for` loops over and over, and which function is used depends on the type of tree, which is specified outside of the main function (by the user).

My problem is that everything inside the `for` loops besides the `edge_weight()` function is identical, so I don't want to copy/paste code.

But at the same time I don't want to condition inside the for loops on which `edge_weight()` function to use, in order to avoid the overhead of a repeated `if` condition.

So what's the cleanest way to specify which function to use before the `for` loops start without copy/pasting the same code?

Can I have pointers to functions (does that slow the code down, though?)?
Can I put functions in variables, arrays?

**EDIT**: Speed is crucial for this application, hence my trying to avoid conditioning inside the `for` loops.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
while(nodes < threshold)        
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i] == something) 
            {
                weight = one_of_two_edge_weight_functions();
```

Comment: I don't see a way around having the logic somewhere to decide which function to call.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, but can you have that logic somehow outside of the while loop?

Comment: Please post a minimal representation of the actual problem.  We might be able to make the calls to the two weight functions in separate batches, but this is not clear from your pseudo-code.

Comment: Unless the edge weight functions are tiny, fast, and inlineable, using a function pointer probably won't slow things down noticeably...

Comment: If the two function are small and pure (don't have side effects), you can call *both* of them and assign the result with a ternary selection (`?:`), which a good compiler will turn into branchless code. However, unless the condition is very poorly predicted or the loop becomes vectorizable through this, there won't be a performance benefit on a modern CPU.

Comment: Yes, function pointers are the way to go in this case.